# Issue with Image which is send Via Mail in iOs default mail app & outlook

Tags: ios, node.js, email, email-templates

I am trying to send Email from node.js API using "node-ses". I attached image url code inside mail body.

```
<img src="' + host + '/images/ic_comscope.png" height="40">
```

It works completely inside Gmail & browser, But having issue in iOs default mail app & outlook.

note: i don't want suggestion related to attachments
Give any other solution

Comment: What was the full URL after it was recieved in email?

Comment: Do you mean the Outlook app on iOS? Or are you talking about the Outlook app on Android, Outlook on Windows, Outlook on Mac, or Outlook.com?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a width to the image instead (OR as well as) the height. E.g. remove `height="40"` and add `style="height: 40px; width: ___px"`. Specifying it in pixels in a style is better for Outlook on Windows if users have different display scaling enabled.